# Promt dialog does not occur on iPad

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using Media Plugin for Xamarin and Windows (`Xam.Plugin.Media`) for taking pictures and `ACR User Dialogs for Xamarin and Windows` with `PromptAsync` afterwards to ask the user for a filename.

It works on iPhone even with iOS 10, but with iPad this error occurs (I have just changed from iPhone app to Universal)

```
Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fe56b79be30> on <Plugin_Media_MediaPickerController: 0x7fe56f192200> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

How can I check, when it is possible to display the Prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, `Acr.UserDialogs` had a constructor, which takes the `UIViewController`, and if I use that constructor, it all went well